# How to remove a duplicated ID in JSON data to have one header data in MAP operation

Tags: javascript

Inside a map operation i get json data like this :

```js
Object.entries(groupBy(matches)).map(([key, value]) => 
  value.map((match, index) => 
    <MatchMonthCard match={match} index={index} key={key + '_' + index}/> 
))
```

and in `<MatchMonthCard>` I have this code :

```js
const team1  = match?.teams?.home;
const team2  = match?.teams?.away;
const league = match?.league;
const venue  = match?.fixture?.venue;
```

```html
<div className="card_header d-flex flex-column g-10">
  <LeagueHeader img={league?.logo} title={league?.name} 
     subtitle={league?.country} />
</div>
<div className="card-padded d-flex flex-column g-20" 
     style={{paddingBottom: variant !=='extended' ? 'var(--card-padding)' : 10}}>
  <div>
    <h3 className="h1">{moment(match?.fixture?.date).format("LT")}</h3>
  </div>
  <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between p-relative">
    <img className="club-logo" src={team1?.logo} alt={team1?.name}/>
    <Score team1={match?.score?.fulltime?.home} 
         team2={match?.score?.fulltime?.away} variant="alt" />
    <img className="club-logo" src={team2?.logo} alt={team2?.name}/>
  </div>
```

the json data is correctly displayed just for `<LeagueHeader>` is repeated for every map operation.

[image]

what I want is to have a one header league for every list of matches, that mean I want to remove the duplicated ID of a league :

Here you can see the duplicated id of header :
[image]

**EDIT**

the json data

```
             "league": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Africa Cup of Nations",
            "country": "World",
            "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/6.png",
            "flag": null,
            "season": 2023,
            "round": "Group Stage - 2"
        },
        "teams": {
            "home": {
                "id": 31,
                "name": "Morocco",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/31.png",
                "winner": null
            },
            "away": {
                "id": 1508,
                "name": "Congo DR",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/1508.png",
                "winner": null
            }
        },
        "goals": {
            "home": 1,
            "away": 1
        },

    .......

                "league": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Africa Cup of Nations",
            "country": "World",
            "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/6.png",
            "flag": null,
            "season": 2023,
            "round": "Group Stage - 2"
        },
        "teams": {
            "home": {
                "id": 1507,
                "name": "Zambia",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/1507.png",
                "winner": null
            },
            "away": {
                "id": 1489,
                "name": "Tanzania",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/1489.png",
                "winner": null
            }
        },
        "goals": {
            "home": 1,
            "away": 1
        },

 ......

             "league": {
            "id": 844,
            "name": "Ligue 1",
            "country": "Congo",
            "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/844.png",
            "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/cd.svg",
            "season": 2023,
            "round": "Regular Season - 11"
        },
        "teams": {
            "home": {
                "id": 3170,
                "name": "Diables Noirs",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3170.png",
                "winner": null
            },
            "away": {
                "id": 16798,
                "name": "V.Club Mokanda",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/16798.png",
                "winner": null
            }
        },
        "goals": {
            "home": null,
            "away": null
        },

   ......
```

**EDIT 2**

and I grouped data by league ID like that:

```
 function groupBy(items) {
    return items.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (curr.league?.id) {
        const { id } = curr.league;
        const currentItems = acc[id];
    
        return { 
          ...acc,
          [id]: currentItems ? [...currentItems, curr] : [curr]
        };
      }
      return acc;
    }, {});
  }
```

**EDIT**

Inside map I did like that to have only name of league one time but still I got the name of league duplicated:

```
const newData = [];
const leagueId = [];

if(leagueId.includes(match?.league.id)){
   const similarityIndex = leagueId.indexOf(match?.league.id);
   newData[similarityIndex].name.push(match?.league?.name);
   newData[similarityIndex].logo.push(match?.league?.logo);
   console.log(1)
  }else{
    newData.push({league:match?.league,name:[match?.league?.name],logo:[match?.league?.logo]})
    leagueId.push(match?.league.id);
    console.log(2)
   }

   console.log(newData[0].name)
```

Comment: You can just take the leagueheader outside of MatchMonthCard and pass one entry of the array leagueheader. So this will have the structure </Leagueheader> and multiple <MatchMonthCard> afterwards. If you are sure that all the matches have same league name.

Comment: No not all the matches have the same league ID, example we have today 3 matches in african cup so I need one header and three matches below but I have repeated id league for the three matches (you can see pictures above),  then another different league ID..., can you provide a clear code to get you?

Comment: I mean the screenshot has 3 matches, with all the same league id. What i want to know is, if you have other matches e.g on the index 7 of your response, do the matches on the response.index.7 have the same league ids? Can you show the full json response?

Comment: Ok I added a JSON DATA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I understood from your question, you want to have the same leagues in one object, so if that's true you need to change your data format. so for that:

```
const newData = [];
const leagueId = [];
matches.forEach((d)=>{
   console.log(d.league.id);
   if(leagueId.includes(d.league.id)){
       const similarityIndex = leagueId.indexOf(d.league.id);
       newData[similarityIndex].teams.push(d.teams);
       newData[similarityIndex].goals.push(d.goals);
      }else{
        newData.push({league:d.league,teams:[d.teams],goals:[d.goals]})
        leagueId.push(d.league.id);
       }
   
 });

console.log(newData);
```

With this change of format, you will not have the same leagues in `newData` , but the teams and goals will become arrays, and each index of the array will correspond to a match.

`newData[0].teams[0]` => `newData[0].goals[0]` => `for one match`

And you may need to make changes to other parts of your code!

Comment: Im not very familiar with JS but I make a new EDIT above, I grouped data by league ID using a function(), but still for matches of a league the league is repeated, your code i guess is so far about what I want, can you provide a code or idea similar to code used above!

Comment: you can use my code as content of your `groupBy(matches)` function .

Comment: Yes Clarify I can't get you?

Comment: I don't know which part of the answer is not clear to you, but the code I wrote integrates the same league data into one of the elements of your array, maybe if you test the code and see the result, it can help you solve your problem.

Comment: I changed the code to make it more understandable, hope it helps

Comment: As I said I did changes and you can see my edit above according to your code but still I have  the same thing, that why I asked you to prove a clear code then I understand what you mean, you can use please  `<LeagueHeader img={league?.logo} title={league?.name} subtitle={league?.country} />`  to understand what you want to do?